# How can I spot domain and https connection attempts to sshd?

Tags: dns, sshd, port-forwarding, https

I'm running my [`sshd(8)`](http://mdoc.su/o/sshd.8) listening on [`domain` and `https` ports](http://openbsd.su/src/etc/services).  (What else is there to run on these ports? :)

Obviously, real DNS (when falling back to TCP) and HTTPS clients might attempt to connect to my SSH server listening on these ports.
How can I find out how many connection attempts it receives from DNS/TCP and HTTPS/TCP clients?
Is there, for example, some pattern that I can search the server's logs for that is unique to a DNS/TCP client or an HTTPS/TCP client talking to an SSH server?
Is there some networking tool that can easily show this?

I have linked the OpenBSD `/etc/services` and `sshd` above, so I'm obviously interested in how to do this on OpenBSD primarily.  But if there's a cross-platform way of doing this that isn't specific to any single operating system, please include it.

Comment: Based on your answer, it seems by domain port you mean ssh port (22). And I guess you mean "how many connection attempts it receives *to these ports* from...", as those aren't the ports DNS normally uses, as you probably know.

Comment: The answer is showing how to recognize this stuff from the log of an SSH server listening on the conventional port, by redirecting some test DNS and HTTPS clients to its port.  The _question_ is talking about SSH servers set up to listen on the non-conventional `domain` and `https` ports, as listed in `/etc/services`, this being the reason _why_ the questioner is interested in recognizing such traffic from logs.

Answer (score 7):

You can add content-based firewall rules that analyze the first few bytes of incoming connections. For example, under Linux, with iptables:

```
iptables -N notssh
iptables -A input -p tcp --dport 443 -m string --algo bm --from 0 --to 7 ! --string SSH-2.0 -j notssh
```

The counter on the `notssh` rule provides the number of times this rule was triggered since it was established or since the counter was reset with `iptables -Z notssh`. There's also a counter on the individual rules.

This incorrectly counts connections where the first packet of the TCP connection contains less than 7 bytes of the SSH protocol but that is rare in practice.

Comment: interesting!  but i don't think that'd work under openbsd. ;)

Comment: @cnst If you are expecting answers specific to OpenBSD, you must state so in your question.

Comment: @xhienne, i'm generally looking for cross-platform solutions.

Comment: @cnst You could apply the same principle on *BSD, but you'd have to use pf syntax, which I don't know.

Comment: @cnst The first sentence is a true generic (cross-platform) solution. The remaining of the post is only an example.

Comment: @cnst if you need solutions to work cross-platform, that's another point to state in your question

Answer (score 4):

A DNS over TCP client can be emulated with [`dig(1)`](http://mdoc.su/o/dig.1) like so (we explicitly use port `22` as the `domain` port might not be translated on the box itself):

```
dig @example.org -p22 +tcp example.org
```

[Or like so](http://cr.yp.to/djbdns/tcp.html#why):

```
dig @example.org -p22 axfr example.org
```

And it appears to result in the following entries at `/var/log/authlog`:

```
Jan 10 15:08:41 example sshd[21075]: Did not receive identification string from 64.124.xxx.xx
Jan 10 15:08:51 example sshd[22052]: Did not receive identification string from 64.124.xxx.xx
Jan 10 15:09:01 example sshd[24980]: Did not receive identification string from 64.124.xxx.xx
```

Whereas https,

```
curl https://example.org:22/
```

appears to result in the following entry (although the number of entries per attempt appears to differ with different browsers):

```
Jan 10 15:25:06 example sshd[9203]: Bad protocol version identification '\\026\\003\\001' from 64.124.xxx.xx
```

It appears that some HTTPS connection attempts also end with one fewer character:

```
Bad protocol version identification '\\026\\003' from
```

We can determine all other possible variations:

```
% fgrep " sshd[" /var/log/authlog | cut -d" " -f7-12 | grep ^Bad | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head
 351 Bad protocol version identification '\\026\\003\\001' from
 110 Bad protocol version identification '\\026\\003\\001\\001E\\001' from
  91 Bad protocol version identification '\\026\\003\\002' from
  63 Bad protocol version identification '\\026\\003\\001\\001=\\001' from
  52 Bad protocol version identification '\\026\\003\\001\\002' from
  44 Bad protocol version identification '\\026\\003\\003' from
  21 Bad protocol version identification '\\026\\003\\001\\001?\\001' from
  16 Bad protocol version identification '\\026\\003\\001\\001B\\001' from
  13 Bad protocol version identification '\\026\\003\\001\\0017\\001' from
  10 Bad protocol version identification '\\026\\003' from
```

We can also see a possible number of `domain` requests:

```
% fgrep " sshd[" /var/log/authlog | cut -d" " -f7-12 | grep ^Did | sort | uniq -c
 227 Did not receive identification string from
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little more complex solution but you could try `sslh` [ssl/ssh multiplexer](http://www.rutschle.net/tech/sslh.shtml) but I guess you will have to manually add checks for DNS packets and you have to configure `sslh` in transparent mode if you need original client's addresses (for `view` in DNS, `allow/deny` in Web-server and `from=` in ssh `authorized_keys`)